# Sequelize - Limiting and ordering inside include

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have associated 3 tables in Sequelize.
[image]
Using findOne am trying to retrieve one room with all messages limited to 10 and with order by message_timestamp but to no avail.

```
models.Room.findOne({
where: {
  room_id: room_id
},
include: [ {
  model: models.Message,
  limit: 10,
  offset: 0,
  order: 'message_timestamp DESC'
} ] })
```

The above code retrieves all the messages (not limited to 10) and are not ordered according to message_timestamp.

Is there a solution? How can I go about doing this?

Thank You.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Do you get any error? Is the result wrong? Provide some problem description

Comment: limit, offset and order are not working. It retrieves one room with ALL the messages.

Answer (score 3):

[You cannot `limit` in an includes statement in sequelize.](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1897) You can only limit from the top-level. With this in mind, you can try something like this:

```
models.Message.findAll({
  include [{
    model: models.Room,
    where: { room_id: room_id }
  }]
  limit: 10,
  offset: 0,
  order: 'message_timestamp DESC'
})
```

Since `include`s are `INNER JOIN`s, it will only retrieve messages where the associated `room_id` = `room_id`

Comment: The problem is I don't have room_id in Message model. Messages and Rooms are associated through RoomMessages.

Comment: Well if you are able to get room_id in the query in your question, you can make that room_id available in your Message query by passing it in as an argument to your Model function, perhaps taken from a query string in the controller. But really it's up to you as to how to make that room_id available where ever that Message query is being called. You don't need to write it in the Message model if you don't want to. You can import the Message model elsewhere to use for queries.